# How to find out whether traffic information is available in the requested area?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google API V3, and JavaScript and want to calculate the delay to get from one point to another that is caused by the traffic.

So, I made two requests (also see code below): One with `durationInTraffic = true` and one with `durationInTraffic = false` Strangely enough, both return the same values (I tested several bigger areas like Munich, Berlin, London, Sidney). Now I wonder whether my code is wrong or there are simply no traffic data available in the requested area.

```
function getRoute(){
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   var myOptions = {
     zoom:7,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };


    var startValue=document.getElementById('start').value;
    var zielValue=document.getElementById('ziel').value;

        var stundeValue=document.getElementById('stunde').value;
    var minuteValue=document.getElementById('minute').value;

    var tagValue=document.getElementById('tag').value;
    var monatValue=document.getElementById('monat').value;
    var jahrValue=document.getElementById('jahr').value;

//departure time in Epoch time
    var abfahrtsZeitValue=monatValue+"/"+tagValue+"/"+jahrValue+" "+stundeValue+":"+minuteValue;

        var request_withTraffic = {
            origin: startValue, 
            destination: zielValue,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            transitOptions: {
                     departureTime: new Date(abfahrtsZeitValue)
                     },
             durationInTraffic: true
        };

        var request_withoutTraffic = {
            origin: startValue, 
            destination: zielValue,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            transitOptions: {
                     departureTime: new Date(abfahrtsZeitValue)
                     },
             durationInTraffic: false
        };

   directionsService.route(request_withTraffic, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

         // Display the duration:
            document.getElementById('durationWithTraffic').innerHTML="Dauer mit Vekehr: "; 
            document.getElementById('durationWithTraffic').innerHTML += 
            response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";            
      }
   });

   directionsService.route(request_withoutTraffic, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {   
            document.getElementById('durationWithoutTraffic').innerHTML="Dauer ohne Verkehr: "; 
            document.getElementById('durationWithoutTraffic').innerHTML += 
            response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";            
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: are you a google maps for work customer? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions - seach for "durationInTraffic (optional) specifies whether the DirectionsLeg result should include a duration that takes into account current traffic conditions. This feature is only available for Google Maps API for Work customers. The time in current traffic will only be returned if traffic information is available in the requested area."

Comment: aka Maps API for Business

Comment: @bnz: Given I am an Google Maps for API V3 for Work customer, do you know where I can put my clientId and signature in my request?